# React native Video, how to dynamically change the source?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get a video to play in React-Native. The problem is that I'm able to use an relative path ("../videos/test.mp4") to achieve this, but when I use a variable like (this.state.path), then I get the following error message below.
Could somebody please help me out?

**ERROR**
[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Wqa.png)

**Main class**

```
export default class level1 extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            path: script[0].path,
            repeat: script[0].repeat,
            finished: false,
            scriptIterator: 0
        }
        this.videoFinished = this.videoFinished.bind(this);
        
    }


    videoFinished() {
        var i = this.state.scriptIterator + 1;
        if (this.state.repeat) {
            // clicklistener
            console.warn("clicklistener");
        }
        
        this.setState({
            finished: false,
            scriptIterator: i,
            path: script[i].path,
            repeat: script[i].repeat
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <VideoClass
                    path={this.state.path}
                    repeat={this.state.repeat}
                    onEnd={this.videoFinished}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const script =
    [
        { path: "../videos/APB.mp4", repeat: false },
        { path: "../videos/test.mp4", repeat: true }
    ]
```

**VideoClass**

```
export default class VideoClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            path: props.path,
            repeat: props.repeat
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Video
                source={require(this.state.path)} 
                style={styles.backgroundVideo}
                muted={true}
                repeat={this.state.repeat}
                resizeMode={"cover"}
                rate={1.0}
                ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
                onEnd={() => this.props.onEnd()}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, in your VideoClass component you should pass `this.props.path` to `source` property and `this.props.repeat` to `repeat` property, since your state is being controlled in your level1 component

```
<Video
     source={this.props.path} 
     style={styles.backgroundVideo}
     muted={true}
     repeat={this.props.repeat}
     resizeMode={"cover"}
     rate={1.0}
     ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
     onEnd={() => this.props.onEnd()}
    />
```

then in your level1 Component you should change your `script` const to:

```
const script =
    [
        { path: require("../videos/APB.mp4"), repeat: false },
        { path: require("../videos/test.mp4"), repeat: true }
    ]
```